# ¿Como obtener números separados de un string C#?

Tags: c#, string

Tengo la siguiente cadena

```
string a = "24 y 25 de enero";
```

lo que quiero hacer es obtener los numeros por separado, es decir {24, 25}

he intentado el siguiente codigo

```
string output = new string(a.ToCharArray().Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

pero obtengo 2425

**Como podria obtener por separado esos numeros?**

Comment: siempre estan en la misma posicion los numeros?

Comment: @gbianchi si, los número siempre están en la misma posición

Comment: y substring no es una opcion?

Comment: @gbianchi quisiera una forma más elegante, primero hice un Split por "y" y luego un substring

Comment: por mas elegante te referis a algo con muchisimo mas codigo?

Comment: Depende si quieres una solución te puedo compartir algo sencillo, o una más "elegante"

Comment: Quieres obtener el string con los números separados por coma o quieres un arreglo con los números.

Comment: @gbianchi, algo sin tanto codigo

Comment: @Ivan-San seria mejor en un arreglo

Comment: Y pq dos lineas de un substring te parecen mucho codigo? O un split y luego quedarte con la fila 0 y 2?

Comment: Hay muchísimas soluciones, podes hasta concatenar `$"{a[0]}{a[1]} {a[5]}{a[6]}";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si lo quieres en un arreglo este es el código apropiado:

> de una forma más elegante.

Separo los elementos por los espacios en la cadena y verifico si el objeto es un número.

```
var a = "24 y 25 de enero";
var array = a.Split(' ').Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out int n));
```

Esto nos regresa un `IEnumerable<string>`

---

Si ocupas un arreglo de `<int>` puedes agregar la siguiente extensión.

```
var array = a.Split(' ').Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out int n)).Select(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x));
```

---

Y para verificar el resultado de una manera notable y distinguida:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{{{string.Join(",",array)}}}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Si los números están en la misma posición siempre podrías probar con:

```
Substring (int startIndex, int length)
```

Indicando la posición de inicio y la longitud de la cadena que quieres y luego lo almacenas en tu array.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es crear un método que recorra la cadena hasta encontrar la letra 'y', de ese modo, efectúas una conversión y obtienes el primer número que sería 24. Luego lo guardas en una variable auxiliar para proceder a obtener el segundo número (25).
Así quedaría el método:

```
class Program
{
    static int GetNumberString(string a, ref int num)
    {
        int i;
        int len = a.Length;
        int aux = 0;
        for(i = 0; i != len; ++i)
        {
            if(a[i] == 'y')
            {
                aux = num;
                num = 0;
            }
            if(a[i] >= '0' && a[i] <= '9')
                num = (num* 10) + (a[i] - '0');
        }
        return aux;
    }
```

Uso del método:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string a = "24 y 25 de enero";
        int num2 = 0;
        int num1 = GetNumberString(a, ref num2);
        Console.Write("Numero1: " + num1 + " Numero2: " + num2);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```